# Magento 2 override pricing / apply custom price on api order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, rest-api

When building an order in the Magento 2.3 admin you can apply custom pricing to line items, is there a way to do this when building an order via the standard Magento 2 API's? If not via the standard API's then how would I best implement this with a custom api endpoint?

Comment: You may create custom API to full fill this need..

Comment: Hi @matthew, i think you can achieve above functionality using this link https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-order-using-rest-api-magento-2/